# How to avoid page with properties when printing?

Tags: printing, cups

I integrated my USB printer (OKI B430) into my network using a Raspberry Pi. Sometimes I get an additional page at the end of a print job.

I usually print PDF documents using the Acrobat Reader 11 and in most
   cases I got such a page.  Also I tried two Word Documents and got an
   additional page once. So I looked at my print options but there is no
   option to avoid this page. Previously the printer was connected via
   USB and there were no such problem.

In my opinion it have to do something with my Raspberry Pi. I am using Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi and CUPS as Printing System.
As addition the additional page contains usually following 3 lines:

```
name_of_file.file_extension"
@PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY = ""
@PJL COMMENT OS VERSION : Windows NT [version]
```

Some additional Informations:

- using Win7 x64
- driver for my printer: OKI B430(PCL) version 1.3.4
- I think it only happens printing more than one page, but I am not sure.

Does anyone have an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: You say 'sometimes'.  The comment shown implies that your Windows system is sending the extra page.  You should take notes of what you were doing, what app you were printing from, what OS, what computer, what you printed... look for consistency and patterns.  But for now, I'd suggest looking at the printer driver properties on the Windows machines.  Your mechanic would laugh if you said "sometimes it makes a noise"... he'd want more information... as do we. :)

Comment: I have added some information. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The three lines look like a 'tail-end' of something from the previous page.  Odd.  Only thing that comes to mind is the possibility of a `JobSheets` option in printers.conf, set to `none, none` should prevent any extra output.  Check your `printers.conf` file in `/etc/cups`.  This is a long shot though.  It still seems like it's a leftover from previous page. (look at first line, it's not really complete.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but "none, none" was the default Setting. Any other idea?

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm out of ideas at the moment.  You mentioned it worked (without extra pages) when direct connected to windows machine, so it's definitely related to RPi and cups.  Sounds like windows is sending data that the cups driver isn't fully processing or isn't expecting as a part of the printout.  I'll tinker with my setup here to see if I can reproduce anything.

Comment: Problem still exist. Anyone else an idea?